# take element ouf of the flexbox flow when the height expands

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In the code snippet below, I have attached an event handler to the first button.

I have also created [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/html-css-js-forked-v9yy6?file=/src/index.js:24-592).

The problem I have is that when the button is clicked, a div is expanded to show more text.

The problem is that because all the divs are in a flexbox container, when the div expands, it pushes down all the other buttons because the height of the textbox container has changed.

Is it possible for the flexbox child to expand without making all of the flexbox children expand.

I need to line the buttons all up at the same level and only one div should appear to expand.

```js
document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document
    .querySelector(".detail-cards-module--expandable__content--kl2yu")
    .classList.add("open");
  document
    .querySelector(".detail-cards-module--header--X5tBT")
    .classList.add("closed");
});

document.querySelector("#btnClose").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document
    .querySelector(".detail-cards-module--expandable__content--kl2yu")
    .classList.remove("open");
  document
    .querySelector(".detail-cards-module--header--X5tBT")
    .classList.remove("closed");
});
```

```css
.detail-cards-module--card-layout {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 5rem;
}

.detail-cards-module--card {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex: 1 1;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.detail-cards-module--header--X5tBT {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1;
  max-height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: relative;
}

.detail-cards-module--statistic--23zwO {
  color: #174383;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: "Lora", serif;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  margin-top: 0.75rem;
}

.detail-cards-module--details--C_LmH {
  flex: 1 1;
}

button {
  z-index: 1;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 1rem 0 1rem;
}

.detail-cards-module--header--X5tBT.closed,
.detail-cards-module--expandable__content--kl2yu {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  max-height: 0;
}

.detail-cards-module--expandable__content--kl2yu.open {
  width: 90%;
  max-height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="detail-cards-module--card-layout">
      <div class="detail-cards-module--card">
        <div class="detail-cards-module--header--X5tBT">
          <h3>
            <p class="rich-text-render-module--para--20qj8">Weight</p>
            <p class="rich-text-render-module--para--20qj8">loss</p>
          </h3>
          <div class="detail-cards-module--statistic--23zwO">93%</div>
          <div class="detail-cards-module--details--C_LmH">
            <p class="rich-text-render-module--para--20qj8">
              decrease in members living with obesity
            </p>
          </div>
          <button id="btn" type="button">open</button>
        </div>
        <div class="detail-cards-module--expandable__content--kl2yu">
          <div>
            <p class="rich-text-render-module--para--20qj8">
              Doggo ipsum smol snoot shoob. Big ol pupper shoober big ol pupper
              I am bekom fat, aqua doggo very jealous pupper heckin good boys
              many pats, puggo wow such tempt porgo. Puggorino waggy wags boof
              ruff what a nice floof, wow very biscit long bois yapper. Heckin
              good boys and girls such treat heckin good boys borking doggo,
              heck extremely cuuuuuute. Borking doggo dat tungg tho thicc ur
              givin me a spook, you are doing me a frighten. Bork such treat
              length boy doing me a frighten very good spot pats, boofers vvv
              fat boi. Tungg shibe smol borking doggo with a long snoot for pats
              noodle horse, pupperino yapper. Aqua doggo puggo much ruin diet
              mlem heckin good boys and girls pupperino you are doing me a
              frighten such treat, doggorino heckin angery woofer sub woofer fat
              boi puggorino.
            </p>
          </div>
          <button id="btnClose" type="button">close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="detail-cards-module--card">
        <div class="detail-cards-module--header--X5tBT">
          <h3>
            <p class="rich-text-render-module--para--20qj8">Free from</p>
            <p class="rich-text-render-module--para--20qj8">medication</p>
          </h3>
          <div class="detail-cards-module--statistic--23zwO">96%</div>
          <div class="detail-cards-module--details--C_LmH">
            <p class="rich-text-render-module--para--20qj8">
              of members have safely come off all medication under medical
              supervision
            </p>
          </div>
          <button id="button1" type="button">open</button>
          <div>&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="detail-cards-module--expandable__content--kl2yu">
          <div>
            <p class="rich-text-render-module--para--20qj8">
              Doggo ipsum smol snoot shoob. Big ol pupper shoober big ol pupper
              I am bekom fat, aqua doggo very jealous pupper heckin good boys
              many pats, puggo wow such tempt porgo. Puggorino waggy wags boof
              ruff what a nice floof, wow very biscit long bois yapper. Heckin
              good boys and girls such treat heckin good boys borking doggo,
              heck extremely cuuuuuute. Borking doggo dat tungg tho thicc ur
              givin me a spook, you are doing me a frighten. Bork such treat
              length boy doing me a frighten very good spot pats, boofers vvv
              fat boi. Tungg shibe smol borking doggo with a long snoot for pats
              noodle horse, pupperino yapper. Aqua doggo puggo much ruin diet
              mlem heckin good boys and girls pupperino you are doing me a
              frighten such treat, doggorino heckin angery woofer sub woofer fat
              boi puggorino.
            </p>
          </div>
          <button type="button">close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="detail-cards-module--card">
        <div class="detail-cards-module--header--X5tBT">
          <h3>
            <p class="rich-text-render-module--para--20qj8">Controlling</p>
            <p class="rich-text-render-module--para--20qj8">blood sugar</p>
          </h3>
          <div class="detail-cards-module--statistic--23zwO">89%</div>
          <div class="detail-cards-module--details--C_LmH">
            <p class="rich-text-render-module--para--20qj8">
              of patients see a X% drop in their HbA1c within X weeks
            </p>
          </div>
          <button type="button">open</button>
          <div>&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="detail-cards-module--expandable__content--kl2yu">
          <div>
            <p class="rich-text-render-module--para--20qj8">
              Doggo ipsum smol snoot shoob. Big ol pupper shoober big ol pupper
              I am bekom fat, aqua doggo very jealous pupper heckin good boys
              many pats, puggo wow such tempt porgo. Puggorino waggy wags boof
              ruff what a nice floof, wow very biscit long bois yapper. Heckin
              good boys and girls such treat heckin good boys borking doggo,
              heck extremely cuuuuuute. Borking doggo dat tungg tho thicc ur
              givin me a spook, you are doing me a frighten. Bork such treat
              length boy doing me a frighten very good spot pats, boofers vvv
              fat boi. Tungg shibe smol borking doggo with a long snoot for pats
              noodle horse, pupperino yapper. Aqua doggo puggo much ruin diet
              mlem heckin good boys and girls pupperino you are doing me a
              frighten such treat, doggorino heckin angery woofer sub woofer fat
              boi puggorino.
            </p>
          </div>
          <button type="button">close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="detail-cards-module--card">
        <div class="detail-cards-module--header--X5tBT">
          <h3>
            <p class="rich-text-render-module--para--20qj8">Lowering</p>
            <p class="rich-text-render-module--para--20qj8">blood pressure</p>
          </h3>
          <div class="detail-cards-module--statistic--23zwO">92%</div>
          <div class="detail-cards-module--details--C_LmH">
            <p class="rich-text-render-module--para--20qj8">
              of patients see their blood pressure go from risky to normal
            </p>
          </div>
          <button type="button">open</button>
          <div>&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="detail-cards-module--expandable__content--kl2yu">
          <div>
            <p class="rich-text-render-module--para--20qj8">
              Doggo ipsum smol snoot shoob. Big ol pupper shoober big ol pupper
              I am bekom fat, aqua doggo very jealous pupper heckin good boys
              many pats, puggo wow such tempt porgo. Puggorino waggy wags boof
              ruff what a nice floof, wow very biscit long bois yapper. Heckin
              good boys and girls such treat heckin good boys borking doggo,
              heck extremely cuuuuuute. Borking doggo dat tungg tho thicc ur
              givin me a spook, you are doing me a frighten. Bork such treat
              length boy doing me a frighten very good spot pats, boofers vvv
              fat boi. Tungg shibe smol borking doggo with a long snoot for pats
              noodle horse, pupperino yapper. Aqua doggo puggo much ruin diet
              mlem heckin good boys and girls pupperino you are doing me a
              frighten such treat, doggorino heckin angery woofer sub woofer fat
              boi puggorino.
            </p>
          </div>
          <button type="button">close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove this CSS

```
.detail-cards-module--details--C_LmH {
    flex: 1 1;
}
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/html-css-js-forked-8mfly)

Comment: thank you .  i need the buttons to align  to the bottom.  i was hoping to avoid making it absolute in a relative container.  do you think this is possible?

Comment: all the alignment has gone if you remove that flex rule